# Generate image with page size and resolution?

Tags: imagemagick

I'd like to use `ImageMagick`'s `convert` to generate bitmaps on the fly.

I would, however, like to specify a page size (say, A4 - which would be internally specified in inches/centimeters), and then specify the resolution in DPI - instead of specifying directly the image size in pixels.

From my looking into the `convert` options, I guessed that the following command line would to the trick:

```
convert -page A4 -density 300x300 xc:white -pointsize 72 -draw "text 25,60 'test'" test.png
```

... unfortunately, this generates a .png image, which is 1x1 pixels in size.

Is what I want to do possible at all with `convert`? If not, are there any other tools that could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, the closest I could get to is this (ImageMagick 6.6.2-6):

```
convert xc:white -page A4 myout.pdf
convert -density 300x300 myout.pdf -pointsize 72 -draw "text 25,235 'test'" myout.png
```

Note that:

- The first command generates proper page size only for `pdf` (but not for `ps`)
- `convert` cannot 'draw' in a vector file like `pdf`
- In the second command, arguments must be given in that order - so that the pdf is taken as a background with known size, on which the text is drawn.

Btw, to obtain the pixel size at a given density of the pdf file:

```
$ convert myout.pdf -format "%[fx:round(w)]x%[fx:h]" info:
595x842
$ convert -density 300x300 myout.pdf -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" info:
2479x3508
```

I guess, this means that what I wanted to do is not possible in a single `convert` command line...

Here is also a code that, in addition, utilizes a gradient:

```
convert xc:white -page A4 myout.pdf
TSIZE=$(convert -density 300x300 myout.pdf -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" info:)
convert -density 300x300 -size $TSIZE myout.pdf gradient:\#4b4-\#bfb -pointsize 72 -draw "text 25,235 'test'" -flatten myout.png
```

Note that the image size, at the given density, must be retrieved in a separate step - as it is required for the gradient; also note the usage of `-flatten` (without it, multiple png files are generated).

References:

- [ImageMagick • View topic - How to create a white A4 rect/pdf page](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13184)
- [ImageMagick: Command-line Options: page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page)
- [Common Formats -- IM v6 Examples: A word about Vector Image formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector)
- [ImageMagick • View topic - Using a formula for the value of -density](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17987)
- [ImageMagick: The Fx Special Effects Image Operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php)
- [Canvas Creation -- IM v6 Examples: Gradients of Color](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#gradient)